# Update map.values() doesn't work

Tags: apex, map, update, after-trigger, after

I don't know why my object's field from map doesn't change. Can you help me please?

```
public void changeCommentAfterUpdate(List<OppDesc__c> newOppDesc){
    Map<Id, Tool__c> mapToConnect = new Map<Id, Tool__c>();
    List<Tool__c> toUpdate = [SELECT Id, Comment__c, Mopp__r.Opportunity__c FROM Tool__c WHERE EndDate__c >=: Date.Today()];

    for (Tool__c t : toUpdate){
        mapToConnect.put(t.Mopp__r.Opportunity__c, t);
    }        
    for(OppDesc__c od : newOppDesc){
        if(od.Comment__c != null && mapToConnect.ContainsKey(od.Opportunity__c)){
            mapToConnect.get(od.Opportunity__c).Comment__c = od.Comment__c;
        }
    }
    update mapToConnect.values(); //After this the tool's comment does't change
}
```

Maybe is something wrong with my trigger?

```
trigger ApartmentsCommentTrigger on OppDesc__c (after update) {
TriggerHelper helperClass = new TriggerHelper();

if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate) {
    helperClass.changeCommentAfterUpdate(Trigger.new);
}
}
```

P.S. `Comment__` is a Long Text Area.

Comment: Code looks ok. Perhaps there's nothing to update, the list returned by `mapToConnect.values()` should show what's going on.

Comment: No. I play a scenario in which there is a change. Perhaps the problem is that there is not just one `Tool__c`, but a `List<Tool__c>`. How to do this right with `Map<Id, List<Tool__c>>`?

Comment: The compiler would not let you save the class if it was a type mismatch.

Comment: No, I'm talking about many Cleanings for each Opportunity. So we even don't know what exactly it updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreeing with David, you need to add WHERE clause to your query and also the names of your variables should be meaningful.

Like you mentioned, I think you are missing multiple tool records for the same opportunity.

```
Map<Id, List<Tool__c>> mapToConnect = new Map<Id, List<Tool__c>>();
List<Tool__c> tools = new List<Tool__c>();

List<Tool__c> toUpdate = [SELECT Id, Comment__c, Mopp__r.Opportunity__c FROM Tool__c];

for (Tool__c t : toUpdate){
    if (t.Mopp__r.Opportunity__c != null) {
        if (!mapToConnect.containsKey(t.Mopp__r.Opportunity__c)) {
            mapToConnect.put(t.Mopp__r.Opportunity__c, new List<Tool__c>());
        }
        mapToConnect.get(t.Mopp__r.Opportunity__c).add(t);
    }
}    

for(OppDesc__c od : newOppDesc){
    if(string.isNotBlank(od.Comment__c) && mapToConnect.ContainsKey(od.Opportunity__c)){
        for (Tool__c tool : mapToConnect.get(od.Opportunity__c)) {
            tool.Comment__c = od.Comment__c;
            tools.add(tool)
        }
    }
}

if(!tools.isEmpty()) {
    update tools;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for help, but it still doesn't work. I updated my code and add the trigger's code. Maybe is something wrong with my trigger?

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Tool__c> toUpdate = [SELECT Id, Comment__c, Mopp__r.Opportunity__c FROM Tool__c];
```

Running an unbounded query like this (no `WHERE` clause) is risky with regard to several limits, as well as general performance. You should update only those records whose state needs to change based on the trigger event.

Your logic here is likely to be the culprit:

```
for (Tool__c t : toUpdate){
    mapToConnect.put(t.Mopp__r.Opportunity__c, t);
}        
for(OppDesc__c od : newOppDesc){
    if(od.Comment__c != null && mapToConnect.ContainsKey(od.Opportunity__c)){
```

Because you *don't* say that you've gotten a `NullPointerException` or somesuch, I suspect that `mapToConnect.ContainsKey()` is always returning `false`, because either the `Mopp__c` or `Opportunity__c` lookup on your `Tool__c` records is `null`.

The basic pattern using `update someMap.values()` is fine.

Comment: In the loop `System.debug(mapToConnect.get(od.Opportunity__c).Comment__c)` it shows me the right value. So, `mapToConnect.ContainsKey()` returns `true`. And I really don't know why it doesn't work. Maybe because of List of Cleanings for each Opportunity. Yes, I know about `WHERE`. It's a test version with a few records.

Comment: I updated my code and add the trigger's code. Maybe is something wrong with my trigger?

Comment: @Apelsinova I think you need to do some debugging and review logs to understand how records are moving through your code. It's hard to square your description of the behavior with what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 1):

You should check in the second `for loop` that if `Comment__c` of custom object `OppDesc__c` is actually `null` or `blank` or `have value` . If `Comment__c` is null then actually there is nothing to update.

`Add a debug log in second for loop` :

```
for(OppDesc__c od : newOppDesc){

    //checking Comment__c is actually null or blank or have value
    System.debug('comment: @startComment-' + od.Comment__c + '-@endComment');

    if(od.Comment__c != null && mapToConnect.ContainsKey(od.Opportunity__c)){
        mapToConnect.get(od.Opportunity__c).Comment__c = od.Comment__c;
    }
}
```